# React native App having api calls - should I use redux?

Tags: react-native, redux

I am starting to build an app in react native and it will be based on too many api calls example, it will have different options upon login for different users so it will be loaded totally based on apis.
Now, I have read about redux a little bit but not able to understand why and what will I benefit from using it in my project. Any directions.

Answer (score 0):

Redux is a state manager , A Predictable State Container for JS Apps. it handle the state of your app, as an example you have 2 diffrent Stacks in your app in one of them you have 3 Screen and in the other you have 2 Screen, so when you wanna have a access from the other stack to another, you need to handle it by passing them as props and there is no place for having the whole state in one place! 
So Redux or any other state manager handle it, you have access to the state of you app whenever you want and you can change it for more info https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research on this, also considered other topics like hooks and state but turns out that this is one of the most recommended approach for writing large react native applications especially when lot of api calls are involved. Hope this helps!